# What voltage does the Creality Ender-3 run at?

Tags: creality-ender-3, replacement-parts

I am pondering about buying a Creality Ender-3, and I am honestly confused about some reviews. Some claim it is running 24 V, one did claim it was 12 V, most don't mention it. Since I know about some issues with the clamps, if I get myself an Ender-3, I want to replace the hotend with a proper one from day one. So knowing its voltage is needed to order the right parts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bearing in mind that the specifications on Amazon's page are sometimes not 100% (even though they are *in this case*), it is always best to check on the manufacturer's website.

From Creality3D's own website, [Creality3D.shop](https://www.creality3dofficial.com/), on the Creality3D Ender-3 product page, [Creality3D Ender-3 3D Printer Economic Ender DIY KITS](https://www.creality3dofficial.com/products/official-creality-ender-3-3d-printer), the specifications are given as (emphasis is mine):

> ##ender-3 Machine Parameter:
>
> - Modeling Technology：FDM (Fused Deposition Modeling）
> - Printing Size：220*220*250mm
> - Machine Size：440*410*465mm
> - Package weight：8kg Max
> - Traveling Speed：180mm/s
> - Filament：1.75mm PLA,TPU,ABS
> - **Input：AC 100-265V 50-60Hz**
> - ***Output：DC 24V 15A 360W***
> - Layer Thickness：0.1-0.4mm
> - Nozzle diameter：0.4mm
> - Precision：±0.1mm
> - File Format：STL,OBJ,G-Code
> - Working Mode：Online or SD offline
> - Max Nozzle Temperature：255℃
> - Max Hot bed Temperature：110℃

Comment: Attention! Creality3d.shop is not the real shop https://www.creality3donline.com is the real online store. this information appears correct though, as it's probably just ripped from the official online store.

Comment: The Creality shop is now https://www.creality3dofficial.com/, as said on their site https://www.creality.com/ (online shop link)

Answer (score 3):

After checking the amazon listings of the ender-3, they contain more information than the gearbest listing: indeed it is a **24V** machine.

> Product description
>
> [...]
>
> **Output: DC 24 V 15 A 360 W**
>
> [...]

Answer (score 2):

The Ender 3 and the CR-10 printers use the same board which runs on both 12V and 24V.  I have one of each and have to be careful swapping parts between the two.

Comment: Really? That is very interesting to know. Please see [What specifications of the dual voltage controller of the Ender 3/CR-10?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6524/what-specifications-of-the-controller-of-the-creality-3d-3)

Comment: I'll go poking around with my voltmeter this weekend and report what I find.