# What are the specifications of the dual voltage controller of the Ender 3/CR-10?

Tags: electronics, creality-cr-10, creality-ender-3

Following on from [What level of voltage does the Creality Ender-3 run at?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6342/what-level-of-voltage-does-the-creality-ender-3-run-at/6521#comment9993_6521)

[Dave's answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6342/what-level-of-voltage-does-the-creality-ender-3-run-at#answer-6521) states that both 12 V and 24 V can be used on the controller board. It also goes on to say that the controller board is used in both configurations in two different printers:

- Ender 3 and;
- CR-10

I would like to know how this dual voltage operation works:

- Does it use both voltages at the same time, or either one or the other?
- Are there two different electrical inlets or are they the same?
- Does it auto-detect or are there jumpers used to configure or are the components tolerant to both voltage levels?

Also related:

- What is the board used?
- Is the board a proprietary design or a standard third party board?
- Does anyone have any photos of the board and/or schematics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I own the Ender 3, and it runs on 24V, as this photo of the power supply shows:
[image: Ender3 Power supply]

From power supply  to the board, it uses a 2-wire line connected with a XT60 plug/jack that is common on RC cars:
[image: XT60 connector on Ender3]

The board itself is a proprietary design and labeled as "V1.1.2". The Voltage in is the lowest input on the left:
[image: Creality3D V1.1.2]

The Cooling fan (blue-yellow wire), the hotend cooling fan, heater cartridge (white shielded), bed heater (left black-red), board cooling fan (middle red-black) run (in this setup) on 24V. The Logic connectors (black-black & White-white) run 5V logic. I could not figure out the voltage of the stepper motors (upper row).

I have not figured out how the power management circut works, but it achieves this:

- Supply voltage $ U_S = 12\ \text V \lor 24\ \text V $
- Logic Voltage $ U_L = 5\ \text V $
- Sensor Voltage $ U_{sens} = U_L$
- Hotend Cooling Fan $ U_{cool} = U_S$
- Hotend Heating Cartridge $ U_{hot} = U_S $
- Heatbed $ U_{bed} = U_S $

The chip's caption can't be read on the photo, but it is labeled as "Δ ATMEL // ATMEGA1284P // AU 1726"

For the pinout, a [german maker](https://www.chaos-drucker.de/anleitungen-und-tutorials/creality-ender3-mit-marlin-ausstatten/) did determine, that it the configuration of a [Sanguino](https://github.com/Lauszus/Sanguino) equipped with an Atmega1284P 16Bit works for compiling firmware and flashing via a bootloader.

Answer (score 3):

This answer addresses the input voltage. If you look up the official replacement board at the official Creality store the board features a single pair of connectors next to it says: 12 V / 24 V. So you can either use 12 V, or 24 V, not both. An internal regulator will most probably reduce the voltage anyways.

[image: Detail of the replacement board, single 12/24 V power connector is encircled]

Please note that (kindly reminded by user profesor79 through the comments) that the microprocessor on these boards only use 5 V. So any voltage you supply (12 or 24 V), the voltage regulator will always make sure the microprocessor does not get more than 5 V. However, that does not necessarily apply to all peripherals connected to the board! This should be verified if for the peripherals also a voltage regulator is used. One of my own boards, [the RUMBA board](https://reprap.org/wiki/RUMBA) can be fed by any voltage ranging from 12 V - 35 V, but this also applies to the peripherals like the heater cartridge and the fans! I use the RUMBA with a 24 V power supply, so I need to use 24 V fans heater elements and heat bed.

Comment: the most important thing to say that the regulator will provide 5V to ttl(Arduino) and the full value of input voltage will be applied to peripherals. Having that in mind - changing PSU voltage will require to change fans, heaters, and even steppers.

Comment: @professor79 Yes totally true, good addition, I did not bother to add that, I will make that more clear

Comment: I can confirm this measurement (after first reading the wrong line and getting a wrong factor in) If U_S=24V, then the bed, fans and heater cartridge run on U=24V, the switches have 5V.